# Getting the file_locator service in symfony2 custom router

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

I want to create a custom route loader as instructed in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html.
What I have to do is read the read the routes from an xml file (not in "symfony xml" format) and create the according route collection.However I want to do that using the '@' directive.as in:

```
xmlRoutes:
    resource: '@FooBarBundle/Resources/routes.xml'
```

But in order to resolve the path to routes.xml I need the 'file_locator' service from the container.is it possible to access services in a custom router class.if not, how can I make a symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator to resolve that path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could access the `file_locator` as it's a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html). What you need to do is make your `custom_route_loader` a service itself (I dind't read the cookbook you linked but I'm pretty sure that they would advice to define it as a service) and inject the `file_locator` service into it.

So basically you'll do something like

```
#config.yml
[...]
services:
  yourbundlename.custom_route_loader:
    class: Path\To\Your\Bundle\CustomRouteLoader
    arguments: [ @file_locator ]
```

And into you CustmRouteLoaderClass

```
#Path\To\Your\Bundle\CustomRouteLoader
class CustomRouteLoader
{
  public function __construct(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Config\FileLocator $file_locator) {
    $this->file_locator = $file_locator;
    [...]
  }
  [...]
}
```